# ¿Por qué la multiplicación con punteros da resultados incorrectos?

Tags: c, punteros

Tengo estos dos apuntadores `p3` y `p4`. Al multiplicarlos y ejecutar me dan un valor muy extraño. ¿Cómo se deben de multiplicar los apuntadores para que den el resultado correcto?

Para tener un poco más de contexto `p3` toma el valor de 30 y `p4` de 10.
El resultado de la operación al ejecutar es 190701600 cuando debe de ser 300.

```c
void main(){
    int w=10, x=20, y=30, z=40, r1,r2,r3;
    int *p1, *p2, *p3, *p4;
    p1=&w;
    p2=&x;
    p3=&y;
    p4=&p1;
    r1=*p1+*p2;
    r2= *p4 * *p3;
    r3= *p2+*p3;
    printf("Los resultados son: %d, %d y %d", r1,r2,r3);
}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). El código se añade como texto así como nadie te va a responder con imágenes para que no tengas que transcribir y quede con errores. 
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Pues con el poco contexto que le das al codigo, la imagen que compartes parece ser la forma correcta de multiplicar los valores a los que apuntan los punteros. Seria bueno que compartieras el resto de tu codigo para que sea mas facil indicarte donde esta el error. Y porfavor, compartelo como texto.

Comment: Editado con codigo

Comment: El problema esta aqui: `p4=&p1;`. A `p4` le estas asignando la direccion de
memoria de `p1`, que es un puntero a un entero, no un entero. Entonces cuando
haces `*p4` estas leyendo la direccion de memoria de `w`, no sus contenidos. La
asignacion correcta es `p4=p1;`. Te recomendaría que activaras los avisos de tu compilador, ya que te hubieran avisado de el problema desde el principio.

Comment: @Pablochaches muchas gracias!!! Tienes razón, te agradezco muchísimo tu aclaración.

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda que usas apuntadores (apuntan a direcciones de objetos), en el apuntador p4 haces que apunte a la direccion de otro aputandor, por lo que te imprime su direccion, para almacenar un apuntador que apunta a otro, debes usar dobles apuntadores.

```
void main(){
int w=10, x=20, y=30, z=40, r1,r2,r3;
int *p1, *p2, *p3, **p4;
p1=&w;
p2=&x;
p3=&y;
p4=&p1;
r1=*p1+*p2;
r2= (**p4) * (*p3);
r3= *p2+*p3;
printf("Los resultados son: %d, %d y %d", r1,r2,r3);
}
```

Tambien puedes apunta a la dirección que contiene el apuntador p1 (w).

```
void main(){
int w=10, x=20, y=30, z=40, r1,r2,r3;
int *p1, *p2, *p3, *p4;
p1=&w;
p2=&x;
p3=&y;
p4=p1;
r1=*p1+*p2;
r2= (*p4) * (*p3);
r3= *p2+*p3;
printf("Los resultados son: %d, %d y %d", r1,r2,r3);
}
```

Solo ten en cuenta que para ambos casos los apuntadores tiene la misma dirección de memoria (w), por lo tanto, cualquiera de los dos apuntadores pueden hacer cambios sobre la misma variable.